# Slightly incorrect information in recommendation letter. Will it get my applications rejected?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I was in professor's Data Structures lab class 3 years ago. Later I co-authored a paper with him. He wrote a very good recommmendation letter for me. However, he stated the course name as ' data structures and algorithms' rather than just ' data structures'.
This seems like a minor mistake and was due to the fact that he left the college long time ago to work in another. And might have mixed up course names. But the letter is very genuine otherwise.

Comment: Did your data structure course contain algorithms to manipulate the data structures? If yes, what are you worried about? Inconsistency between your transcript and the rec.  letter? If yes, why would anyone care about this minor typo (extra info)? Do you have other reasons to worry about this?

Comment: Its just the slight discrepancy in course names I was worried about.  In the transcript it just says data structures.

Comment: No it should not be a problem.

Comment: I am not even sure if anyone would notice this. And if they do - course titles are not set in stone and can change between the time the transcript was made and the letter was written.

Answer (score 16):

I suggest not to worry about it. Your transcript probably is an auto-generated document with the official course title. On the other hand, the letter is written by a human who might have worked from memory, or, as @Pikachu피카츄 points out in a comment, might have tried to make the title more descriptive. In any case, the letter will be read by humans who certainly will be able to understand how such a minor inconsistency occurs.

Comment: The official titles of the courses are sometimes not so informative (e.g Maths I, Maths II, Maths III) that my professors decided to use other titles such as Real Analysis, Differential Calculus, ... instead. Still, there's no problem. Maybe it's even better to do it this way.

Comment: @Pikachu피카츄, right, I added your point to the answer.

Comment: I somehow by mistake downvoted your answer. Had to edit it to upvote.